# Why does my app closes when iniating map from Xamarin.Forms.GoogleMaps?

Tags: c#, google-maps, xamarin.forms, maps, nuget-package

The app only has a map and a pin, when the app starts takes like 2 seconds in the splash screens and then closes.

I've tried adding the same map in an another crossplatform app that's working and happens the same, when I tap to go to the page that only has the map it gets closed.

There are no exceptions or errors whatsoever.

Using nuget package Xamarin.Forms.GoogleMaps 3.3.0

Here's my code:
https://github.com/hernandeztechy/TestGoogleMap

Answer (score 0):

There are some exceptions in your APP but you can not find so it is closed.

try to find them you can add try and catch in the code where you add the `pin` and `map`

then you will find the exceptions.

there will be some exception that the vs studio can not find.not all exceptions the vs will tell you .

Answer (score 0):

in the console output

> [Google Maps Android API] Authorization failure.  Please see
> https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-api/start for
> how to correctly set up the map. [Google Maps Android API] In the
> Google Developer Console (https://console.developers.google.com)
> [Google Maps Android API] Ensure that the "Google Maps Android API v2"
> is enabled. [Google Maps Android API] Ensure that the following
> Android Key exists: